# GCC does not throw an error during the compiler stage when a function has not been forward declared

Tags: c, unix, gcc

Ok,

I have 3 files in my directory.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int a, int b, int c)
{
    aprint();
    bprint();
}
```

a.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void aprint()
{
    printf("hey This is a.c");
}
```

b.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void bprint()
{
   printf("This is b.c");
}
```

I haven't created any header files. 
I just compiled using "gcc main.c a.c b.c" 
I didn't get any error. I want to know what happened? 
Did gcc just assume everything is going to be okay in linking stages and why didn't gcc throw an error during compilation?

Comment: You have of course enabled all warnings?

Comment: The type control of C is less strict than the type control C++. gcc will assume aprint(); means int aprint(void). Therefore it is valid C.

Comment: @hetepeperfan It is undefined behaviour in C90, the type used to call `aprint` and `bprint` is not the type the functions actually have. It is invalid in C99 and later, since implicit function declarations have been removed from the language in C99. Of course, by default gcc compiles in `gnu89` mode, and then it assumes a return type of `int` without prior declaration. If the definitions were in the same translation unit, a diagnostic message would be required, but since they are in different translation units, the compiler doesn't know that the types aren't compatible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enable warnings using -Wall flag, hten you will see warning: Implicit call to function bprint() and Implicit call to function aprint(). It's is basically compiler recognizes this function during Linker stage and this does not give any error.

Answer (score 3):

C89/90 version of C language does not require functions to be forward declared. C99 version of C language does require functions to be forward declared. Are you compiling your code in C89/90 mode or in C99 mode?

Note that even in C99 mode a genuine error (i.e. a constraint violation) might be reported by the compiler as a mere warning. If you want GCC to become more strict in reporting constraint  violations as errors, run it with `-pedantic-errors` switch.

Answer (score 2):

I brought you your warnings:

```
notroot@ubuntu:~/qweqwe$ gcc main.c a.c b.c -Wall
main.c:2:5: warning: second argument of ‘main’ should be ‘char **’ [-Wmain]
main.c:2:5: warning: third argument of ‘main’ should probably be ‘char **’ [-Wmain]
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:4:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘aprint’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
main.c:5:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘bprint’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
main.c:6:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```